# Unit testing for a function (tolower) using pointers

Tags: c, unit-testing, pointers, tolower

I have this function that changes the string to all lower cases.

I am trying to create a unit test for this function, but I think I am passing the argument wrong, and I get this error.

```
Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
```

This is my code.

```
void example (char const * str1, int length, char * str2) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        *(str2 + i) = putchar(tolower( *(str1 + i) ));
    }
}

void testexample() {
    char * str1 = "TEST";
    char * str2 = "";
    example( str1, 4, str2);
    printf("%s\n", *str2);
}

int main() {
    testexample();
    return 0;
}
```

str1 is the original string, and n is the length of the string, and str2 is the all lower case version of str1.

I've been stuck trying to solve this problem for a while now.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: How did this even compile?

Comment: `str2` points to a string literal, which is likely read-only... and it's not even long enough to copy `str1` into anyway.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.16 Assignment operators Constraints
2
An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.*, *6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators [...]A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-
qualified type,[...]*. Your compiler was obligated to issue a diagnostic message.

Comment: From the issues with your code it's clear that you don't know some fundamentals about the c programming language, I suggest reading about it and then try this again. For instance, do you know that `putchar()` does? Do you understand that string literals are read only? Do you understand that arrays do not grow automatically in c? Do you know that strings in c are arrays?

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped. Str2 is not const. I updated it.

Comment: @neko_studies_prog That means nothing, `str2` is still read only because it points to a string literal. The `const ` would merely prevent it from compiling.  And also, if you make it an array and initialize it with the literal `""` then there is no enough room, you can try `char str2[5]`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: It does mean that *this* remaining error is not automatically caught by the compiler.

Comment: @EOF I stand corrected, it's not better and it's not the same, it's worst.

Answer (score 0):

In your main:

```
char * str2 = "";
```

and then you pass `str2` as a parameter, but it has too little storage and that storage is further read-only memory (points to a literal). The result is your crash. Use:

```
char str2[32] = 0;
```

or any length you need, including a null terminating character.

Comment: `char c; c = 'a';` I see no problem with assigning to characters.

Comment: You're not even beginning to make sense.

Comment: @EOF,...eh.. I was in pointer conflict mode (resulting in not making sense :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

also you write `printf("%s", *str2)`. if str2 is a string so *str2 is a char.